# Drawing Arrows article in c++ builder borland-issue with linker

Tags: winforms, canvas, borland-c++

my question is related to aritcle link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3274/Drawing-Arrows

I did:

```
a.nWidth = 10;
a.fTheta = 0.3f;
a.bFill = true;
Canvas->MoveTo(100, 100);
HDC hDC = GetDC(Canvas->Handle);
ArrowTo(hDC, 200, 100, &a);
```

And I got linker error:"Unresolved external 'ArrowTo(void *, int, int, tARROWSTRUCT *)' referenced"

Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like `ArrowTo` is not defined inside `windows.h` is this GDI+ perhaps? in that case you need to link it from somewhere because that is not part of standard WinAPI. Try to locate dll where this is supposed to be and link it. But faster and simpler would be encode the function from standard GDI functions its really just few lines of code (to obtain the 2 missing points ...) see [Find coordinates to draw arrow head](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31469874/2521214)

Comment: Thanks you for your support!

Comment: There is no Win32 API function named `ArrowTo()`. It looks like the OP is using code from CodeProject instead: [Drawing Arrows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3274/Drawing-Arrows). To resolve the error, you need to add the provided `Arrow.cpp` file to your project, it is not enough to just `#include` the `Arrow.h` file.