# Algorithms for drawing a line towards a rectangle but terminating just before the rectangle

Tags: graphics

I have two squares and I want to draw a line between them but the lines should terminate just before reaching the rectangle perimeter. See the figure below to see what I mean. If you extend the lines they will originate from the center of each square. My question is whether there is a standard way to deal with this problem in computer graphics?

[image]

In the past I've drawn a larger invisible rectangle around the visible rectangle and then look for which edge of the invisible rectangle the line intersects. I use the intersection points as the start and end coordinates to draw the line. I also need one of the intersection points on to which to draw an arrow, but I know how to do that, given the slope of the line etc. This means I can't simply draw the line from center to center then draw rectangles on top. If there isn't a better way I use what I currently do.

Comment: I just saw you mention arrows so  what exactly do you mean by arrow? you want that line to be an arrow? single or bidirectional?  what shape? 30-60 deg arrow head is the usual... however 90 deg  is easier (does not require rotation formula nor atan2 ...) head is (filled) triangle or 2 lines? what size (constant, scaled line length, ... ?)

Comment: I mean an arrowhead at the end of one of the lines to indicate direction. What I do is create some coordinates for a horizontal arrow shape then rotate and translate the arrow to the tip. Works quite well. The arrows can be filled with a different color and there is scaling to accommodate any user zooms.

Comment: see [Find coordinates to draw arrow head (isoscele triangle) at the end of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469874/2521214) completely forgot that one QA ... :) looks like I managed to do it without any goniometrics

Comment: Very useful post, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. **math approach**

   You can simply compute the endpoints of line. So just translate it inwards by the  intersected part of rectangle and + some gap distance. for axis aligned rectangle should be quite easy math

   [image: sketch]

   so first endpoint `E` can be computed like this:

   ```cpp
   a = rectangle A width
   d = B-A; // line direction
   C = A + d*dot( d , (0,a/2) );
   E = C + gap*d/|d|;
   ```

   the other endpoint can be done analogicaly in the same way. You just need to know which side the line hits. So pick the one for which is the dot `>=0` but minimal:

   ```cpp
   dot( d , (0,+a/2) )
   dot( d , (0,-a/2) )
   dot( d , (+b/2,0) )
   dot( d , (-b/2,0) )
   ```

   where `b` is rectangle height... so when put together:

   ```cpp
   a = rectangle A width
   b = rectangle A height
   t = 1.0;
   d = B-A; // line direction
   x = dot( d , (0,+a/2) ); if ((x>=0)&&(x<t)) t=x;
   x = dot( d , (0,-a/2) ); if ((x>=0)&&(x<t)) t=x;
   x = dot( d , (+b/2,0) ); if ((x>=0)&&(x<t)) t=x;
   x = dot( d , (-b/2,0) ); if ((x>=0)&&(x<t)) t=x;
   C = A + d*t;
   E = C + gap*d/|d|;
   ```
2. **graphics approach**

   1. render line
   2. render enlarged rectangles by gap filled only by backgroud color
   3. render your rectangles

   this approach flickers so you need to use any back/double buffering method. Its also slower as it need to render the rectangles twice at runtime. Also the line is cut by the rectangle side so if it is thick line it might not look as expected